# Rank order data

Tags: excel, sorting, statistics, analytics, ranking

I have the loan dataset below -

| Sector | Total Units | Bad units | Bad Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Retail Trade | 16 | 5 | 31% |
| Construction | 500 | 1100 | 20% |
| Healthcare | 165 | 55 | 33% |
| Mining | 3 | 2 | 67% |
| Utilities | 56 | 19 | 34% |
| Other | 300 | 44 | 15% |

How can I create a ranking function to sort this data based on the bad_rate while also accounting for the number of units ?

e.g This is the result when I sort in descending order based on bad_rate

| Sector | Total Units | Bad units | Bad Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mining | 3 | 2 | 67% |
| Utilities | 56 | 19 | 34% |
| Healthcare | 165 | 55 | 33% |
| Retail Trade | 16 | 5 | 31% |
| Construction | 500 | 1100 | 20% |
| Other | 300 | 44 | 15% |

Here, Mining shows up first but I don't really care about this sector as it only has a total of 3 units. I would like construction, other and healthcare to show up on the top as they have more # of total as well as bad units

Comment: How is there 1100 bad units out of 500 total?  Probably a typo.

Comment: you will need to be more specific as to the weight you are giving things.  Other wise the answer is to sort descending on the Bad units.

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1)**  is easy...
Use `SORT("Range","ByColNumber","Order")`
Just put it in the top left cell of where you want your sorted data.

> `=SORT(B3:E8,4,-1)`:

[image]
[image]

---

**STEP 2)**

Here's the tricky part... you need to decide how to weight the outage.
Here, I found multiplying the Rate% by the Total Unit Rank:

[image]

I think this approach gives pretty good results... you just need to play with the formula!
Please let me know what formula you eventually use!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define sorting criteria, since you don't have a priority based on column, but a combination instead. I would suggest defining a function that weights both columns: **Total Units** and **Bad Rate**. Using a weight function would be a good idea, but first, we would need to normalize both columns. For example put the data in a range `0-100`, so we can weight each column having similar values. Once you have the data normalized then you can use criteria like this:

```
w_1 * x + w_2 * y
```

This is the main idea. Now to put this logic in Excel. We create an additional temporary variable with the previous calculation and name it `crit`. We Define a user `LAMBDA` function `SORT_BY` for calculating `crit` as follows:

```
LAMBDA(a,b, wu*a + wbr*b)
```

and we use `MAP` to calculate it with the normalized data. For convenience we define another user `LAMBDA` function to normalize the data: `NORM` as follows:

```
 LAMBDA(x, 100*(x-MIN(x))/(MAX(x) - MIN(x)))
```

**Note**: The above formula ensures a `0-100` range, but because we are going to use weights maybe it is better to use a `1-100` range, so the weight takes effect for the minimum value too. In such case it can be defined as follow:

```
LAMBDA(x, ( 100*(x-MIN(x)) + (MAX(x)-x) )/(MAX(x)-MIN(x)))
```

Here is the formula normalizing for `0-100` range:

```
=LET(wu, 0.6, wbr, 0.8, u, B2:B7, br, D2:D7, SORT_BY, LAMBDA(a,b, wu*a + wbr*b),
 NORM, LAMBDA(x, 100*(x-MIN(x))/(MAX(x) - MIN(x))),
 crit, MAP(NORM(u), NORM(br), LAMBDA(a,b, SORT_BY(a,b))),
 DROP(SORT(HSTACK(A2:D7, crit),5,-1),,-1))
```

You can customize how to weight each column (via `wu` for **Total Units** and `wbr` for **Bad Rates** columns). Finally, we present the result removing the sorting criteria (`crit`) via the `DROP` function. If you want to show it, then remove this step.

If you put the formula in `F2` this would be the output:
[image: excel output]